# Javascript nested loop crashes browser

Tags: javascript, html, loops, browser, nested

I am creating a web app with Django and I require some Javascript for changing styles of dynamically generated elements. I have simplified the code to just static html and javascript.

Goal:
The code causing problems is acting on detail pages.
There are many detail pages, each representing data from a given database entry.
Each page will have 1 or more table, depending on how many protein names the database entry has.
For each table, I want to change the colour of the entry for the protein name in the table heading as well as the entry for the example_id.

Attempt:
I am using javascript to capture the example_id from the top level heading and the protein names from the table headings.
I am then capturing the nodelist of table rows and iterating through, looking for entries that match either the protein name or the example_id.

Problem:
When iterating over the nodelist of protein names taken from the table headers in a nested loop the page never loads.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 class="msaIdCatcher">Protein Record #example_id</h1>
    
      <h2>Multiple Sequence Alignment</h2>

        


        <h3 class= "msaProtNameCatcher">Protein_name1</h3>
          <p>The following is a multiple sequence alignment (MSA) of all sequences predicted to be Protein_name1 sequences.</p>

          <table>

            <tr class=sequenceidrow>
              <th class=sequenceid>not_example_id1</th>
              <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=sequenceidrow>
              <th class=sequenceid>Protein_name1</th>
              <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=sequenceidrow>
              <th class=sequenceid>not_example_id3</th>
              <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=sequenceidrow>
              <th class=sequenceid>example_id</th>
              <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=sequenceidrow>
              <th class=sequenceid>not_example_id4</th>
              <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <h3 class="msaProtNameCatcher">Protein_name2</h3>
          <p>The following is a multiple sequence alignment (MSA) of all sequences predicted to be Protein_name2 sequences.</p>

          <table>
            <tr class=sequenceidrow>
              <th class=sequenceid>not_example_id1</th>
              <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class=sequenceidrow>
              <th class=sequenceid>not_example_id2</th>
              <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=sequenceidrow>
                  <th class=sequenceid>not_example_id3</th>
                  <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=sequenceidrow>
                  <th class=sequenceid>example_id</th>
                  <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=sequenceidrow>
                  <th class=sequenceid>not_example_id4</th>
                  <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class=sequenceidrow>
                  <th class=sequenceid>Protein_name2</th>
                  <td class="alignsequence">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
var idTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("msaIdCatcher");
id = idTitle[0].innerHTML;
id = id.replace("Protein Record #", "");

//Get protein_names from table headers
proteinnameElements = document.getElementsByClassName("msaProtNameCatcher")

//Get table rows
var sequenceidrowElements = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceidrow");

//Loop through table rows
for (var i = 0; i < sequenceidrowElements.length; i++) {

    //Get sequence id
    var sequenceidElement = sequenceidrowElements[i].getElementsByClassName("sequenceid");
    idElement = sequenceidElement[0].innerHTML

    //Check if ID is ID from page heading
    if (idElement == id) {

        //Get sequence element and change colour of ID and sequence elemnt
        var alignsequenceElement = sequenceidrowElements[i].getElementsByClassName("alignsequence");
        sequenceidElement[0].style.color = "#b80090";
        alignsequenceElement[0].style.color = "#b80090";
    }

    //Loop through protein names in table headers and Check if ID in table matches protein name
    //Then change colour of ID and sequence
    for (var i = 0; i < proteinnameElements.length; i++) {
        proteinname = proteinnameElements[i].innerHTML
        if (idElement == proteinname) {
            var alignsequenceElement = sequenceidrowElements[i].getElementsByClassName("alignsequence");
            sequenceidElement[0].style.color = "red";
            alignsequenceElement[0].style.color = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

```
However, when using a single protein name by making proteinname equal to the innerHTML of the first element proteinnameElements and taking away the loop nesting as follows, the page loads in a fraction of a second.
```

```
var idTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("msaIdCatcher");
id = idTitle[0].innerHTML;
id = id.replace("Protein Record #", "");

//Get protein_names from table headers
proteinnameElements = document.getElementsByClassName("msaProtNameCatcher")
proteinname = proteinnameElements[0].innerHTML
//Get table rows
var sequenceidrowElements = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceidrow");

//Loop through table rows
for (var i = 0; i < sequenceidrowElements.length; i++) {

    //Get sequence id
    var sequenceidElement = sequenceidrowElements[i].getElementsByClassName("sequenceid");
    idElement = sequenceidElement[0].innerHTML

    //Check if ID is ID from page heading
    if (idElement == id) {

        //Get sequence element and change colour of ID and sequence elemnt
        var alignsequenceElement = sequenceidrowElements[i].getElementsByClassName("alignsequence");
        sequenceidElement[0].style.color = "#b80090";
        alignsequenceElement[0].style.color = "#b80090";
    }

    //Loop through protein names in table headers and Check if ID in table matches protein name
    //Then change colour of ID and sequence
        if (idElement == proteinname) {
            var alignsequenceElement = sequenceidrowElements[i].getElementsByClassName("alignsequence");
            sequenceidElement[0].style.color = "red";
            alignsequenceElement[0].style.color = "red";
        }
}
```

```
Can someone help me understand why nesting loops in this way causes such a large difference in runtime and help me find a way to solve my problem?

Thanks!
```

Comment: You are using in both loops var i

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop begins with `var i`, because of how scoping works in JavaScript, it will be the same `i` as the outer loop, and it will be changed everytime the inner loop is run (thereby never increasing the outer loop, making it endless); it's like typing this:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    for (i = 0; i < length2; ++i)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Either use a different variable name for the inner loop (`j` is a common choice), or use the `let` keyword (which will ensure the variables are locally scoped), this is the let keyword (note that it's relatively recent):

```
for (let i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps clear things up.